# Update single row of data frame in R

Tags: r

my dataframe:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Setosa | 1 |
| Versicolor | 2 |

So first of all, I want to check if an input matches the name in any row.

My solution for the filter so far:

```
# input$df <- Versicolor

import dplyr
df_table <- df_table %>%
      dplyr::filter(grepl(input$df, Name, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

If there is a match, I'd like to update/overwrite this row with new values, like in the following table:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Setosa | 1 |
| Versicolor | 3 |

The name stays the same, but only the value changes.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: This looks like it's from a Shiny app.  How do you pick the new value?  Does the same new value apply to all matches if there are multiples?

Comment: The new value is actually a date() function but I simplified it in this post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```r
df_table[df_table$Name == input$df, 'Value'] <- new_value
```

This will update the `Value` column for all rows where the value in `Name` is the same as `input$df` which in your example is `Versicolor`

Answer (score 0):

We can use a join

```
library(dplyr)
df_table %>%
    left_join(input, by = c("Name")) %>%
    mutate(Value = coalesce(Value.x, Value.x), .keep = "unused")
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_table)[input, Value := i.Value, on = .(Name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use {powerjoin} :

```r
library(powerjoin)

df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Setosa", "Versicolor"), Value = c(1, 2))
df2 <- data.frame(Name = "Versicolor", Value = 3)

power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "Name", conflict = coalesce_yx)
#>         Name Value
#> 1     Setosa     1
#> 2 Versicolor     3

# or doing a row-wise sum:
power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "Name", conflict = rw ~ sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE))
#>         Name Value
#> 1     Setosa     1
#> 2 Versicolor     5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>